# How we can show doted navigation for next and previous screens in android?

Tags: java, android

[image]

I want to show dots for next and previous and for go to specific screen in android by click on that dots. 
Can use the image like dots to do this? 
and can i know the code for this?

Comment: Please delete this Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start intents when the user clicks one of your images.  You can also tell where the user came from by using bundles, and customise your back button to return to the intent that sent the bundle.